Cambio de zona horaria en Oracle Solaris 5.10 Thu Apr 25 12:43:50 COT 2024
Cambio de zona horaria en Oracle Solaris 5.10
Thu Apr 25 12:43:50 COT 2024
Quiero mostrar la fecha de la siguiente manera
Cambiar a UTC 25/04/2024  11:00:00 a. m.

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Bienvenido . agrega lo que tratate o investigaste, revisa [ask].

dónde quieres mostrar la fecha?

Tengo una maquina con SunOS 5.10 SOLARIS Necesito realizar el cambio de zona horari. La maquina Oracle Solaris 5.10 Muestra la hora de la siguiente manera:
Thu Apr 25 12:43:50 COT 2024
Y Quiero mostrar la fecha de la siguiente manera:
UTC 25/04/2024  11:00:00 a. m.

Tengo una maquina (Servidor) con el sistema operativo SunOS 5.10 SOLARIS Necesito realizar el cambio de zona horaria del servidor. La maquina Oracle Solaris 5.10 Muestra la hora de la siguiente manera:
Thu Apr 25 12:43:50 COT 2024
Y Quiero mostrar la fecha de la siguiente manera:
25/04/2024  11:00:00 a. m. UTC  es decir cambiar el formato y zona horaria del servidor.

No repitas tu pregunta.. aprende a usar el sitio.. este sitio es sobre programacion, no sobre configuracion de servidores... podrias probar en el sitio de unix (en ingles)
